# Has anyone here tried this alternative peer review platform 'Peerage of Science'?

Tags: journals, peer-review, online-publication, open-science

I have just learnt about the details of this platform, located below:
https://www.peerageofscience.org

I am interested in trying out but none of my colleagues has experimented this platform. I am worried whether this would delay my publication process or end up limiting my options of journals (my 1st choice journal is not in their list but I could appreciate trying out one of their options). Or even if this is seen with good eyes by my peers.

Please anyone here who has submitted a paper to this website, or followed such a submission, could you please share details of your experience?

Comment: Agreed, though I am right now particularly interested in the platform. It seem, however, that everyone else here is also still thinking of jumping in these waters...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Peerage of Science received 102 submissions in 2017. Some submissions get zero reviews, but those that are reviewed have a decent chance of getting publishing offers from participating journals: 60% received at least one publishing offer, some got 4 or 5 offers. The other submissions - probably - got negative reviews and then of course do not attract journals either.

But as an author your options are **not limited** to participating journals; you can always choose to decline offers, and also "export" the review to any journal of your choice (= create a link that you can give to any editor of any journal, giving them access to this one process reviews in Peerage of Science). It is then of course up to the receiving editor if and how they want to use those reviews, but Peerage of Science makes them available and trustable (it's not a PDF author gives them, but password-protected link to content on peerageofscience.org website that author can not modify).

So give it a try! I can't promise your work will get reviews, and **certainly** shall **not** promise you will get positive reviews - Peerage of Science is about doing peer review rigorously and well, not quick and easy. But there's little you can lose, as it is free, you get to stay anonymous as author, and **you** define the deadlines.

Full disclosure: I am the founder of Peerage of Science.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for disclosing of internal details here! Have you included stats directly on the website? I'd interested in seeing some more numbers, e.g. how many get no reviews, and mean+variance of response time from reviewers. I believe your initiative is great.

Comment: What about the risk that journals will consider it a prior publication?

Comment: Scientist: no real-time stats at present, may develop in the future. Authors set the deadlines, and like always people tend to do things on the last possible day. However, peer-review-of-peer-review stage (where reviewers judge and score each other) is an exception and median completion time is ca 48h, even though deadline is 7 days. @Tobias: Peerage of Science is not open to public, thus there is no "publication". Only verified scientists have access to manuscripts during review, and completed processes are only visible to authors themselves, participating reviewers and editors.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the manuscript is only visible to peer reviewers and journal editors, as with any submission to any journal. [I am a PoS reviewer]

Answer (score 3):

I have submitted some mathematics articles for review there. The website was poorly made for this purpose (one needed to submit an editable file, rather than a PDF, and there was no integration with Arxiv such as a possibility to simply submit an arxiv link) and I got no reviews. A biologist would likely have a better chance and experience.

Comment: In the end I haven't tried the platform yet. I will update here when I do !..