# List of peer review platforms and social networks

Tags: mathematics, peer-review, networking, social-media

I recently stumbled upon [Publons](https://publons.com/home/), a social network of peer reviewers, with a database of potential reviewers, along with their areas of expertise, stats, and contact details. I wonder if there are more platforms like this? Can we make a list of serious websites dedicated to reviewers or peer review? If there are some specialized in Mathematics, I'd like to hear about them.

Comment: You claim Publons is "a social network for peer reviewing," whereas Publons seems to be a social network that lists peer reviews (cf. "Publons helps you get the recognition you deserve for keeping watch over science and research" from their home page), hence, it isn't concerned with peer reviewing. Could you clarify?

Comment: @user2768 Sorry, I meant "of peer reviewers" (I'll edit). The important part is that of the database of potential reviewers, so that editors can find their reviewers there

Comment: I expect most journals to have a "database of potential reviewers".

Comment: @Roland Yes, but you cannot add yourself to most of them, and have public certification and feedback, unless I'm mistaken

Comment: Who would want to get more review requests? If you are not busy enough, do more research and publish. That is the traditional way of getting into such databases.

Comment: The editors tend to pick reviewers from those who publish AND get referenced by others in a particular field - as such, it “proves” their credibility. While if editors relied on a list of “I am the best” ego driven uncontrolled etc what would happen...

Comment: In my opinion, this question is **on-topic** and shall be open again. The question underlines important information about both academic and research fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think Publons provides what you’re searching for. If you’re looking for potential reviewers I’d suggest you to look into F1000, PeerJ, Peerage of Science.

The latter I’ve come across with a while ago, see question below.

http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102720/has-anyone-here-tried-this-alternative-peer-review-platform-peerage-of-science

Good luck!